# Checking if a nsstring matches another string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Suppose I have a string "167282". How can I check if the string contains "128"? Is there any provision to know the percentage of the 2nd string that matches the first string? (If all the characters of the 2nd string are present in the first string or not.) Please help and thanx in advance.

Comment: hi Shyam, this isnt a site where you can give thanx in advance, when someone answers your question make sure you come back and give them an upvote and if appropriate mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

```
NSString *compareString = @"128";
NSCharacterSet *compareCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"167282"];

NSUInteger strLen = [compareString length];
NSUInteger matchingCount = 0;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < strLen; ++i) {
  if ([compareCharSet characterIsMember:[compareString characterAtIndex:i]])
    ++matchingCount;
}

float percentMatching = matchingCount/(float)strLen;
```

Where matchingCount will be the number of characters in compareString that match a character in @"167282" and percentMatching will be the percent of total characters in compareString that match. This is, as best as I can tell, what you intended with your question - the concept of a percent match wouldn't make any sense otherwise.

Comment: What i need originally is to check whether a string say for example 14672 has characters 1,3,7 in it.To get whether all the 3 characters are present or 2 of them are present or none of them are present in my string

Comment: That's exactly what this snippet is meant to do then, Shyam. If one of the answers provided is what you were looking for, you should upvote it and/or mark it as the accepted answer using the green checkmark.

Comment: Accepting an answer (green checkmark) is even more important as the questioner, since it contributes to your “percent accepted” score. If you never accept answers, some people will be less likely to answer any further questions from you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)'s [`rangeOfString`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:) method to find out whether a string contains another string, as suggested by the answers to [this question on the Apple Mailing Lists](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2003/Jan/msg00520.html).

```
if ([@"167282" rangeOfString:@"128"].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"String contains '128'.");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"String doesn't contain '128'.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method [`rangeOfString:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:) to check whether or not your original string contains your desired substring. This method will return an `NSRange` with the location of your substring within the original string:

```
[@"12345" rangeOfString:@"123"]; // Gives range {0, 3}
[@"12345" rangeOfString:@"345"]; // Gives range {2, 3}
[@"12345" rangeOfString:@"678"]; // Gives range {NSNotFound, 0}
```

This only works if the substring is *entirely contained* within the original string.

As for the "amount correct," you can use the `length` property of the returned range, along with the length of the original string, to see what part of the original string is comprised by the substring. For example:

```
NSRange r = [@"1234" rangeOfString:@"1"]; // Range {0, 1}
float portion = (float)r.length / (float)[@"1234" length]; // Gives 0.25f
```

Keep in mind this will fall apart if the substring is repeated - checking for `@"1"` as the substring of `@"111"` will give only the first occurrence, meaning it'll claim the string is "33% correct" by this method. Depending on your intended use, this may or may not be what you want.