# Checking the existane of a particular character in an array of strings

Tags: iphone

i have an array of strings say for example  @"123",@"373",@"221",@"921" .I need to check in how many elements of that array 2 exists and want to concatenate those elements into a mutable string and finally eradicate all two and prepare a string.I should have a string 13373191 out of the above example

Comment: I already answered one of your homework-y questions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781440/checking-if-a-nsstring-matches-another-string. Similar concepts presented in my answer and in the other answers in that question should get you what you need.

Comment: its not a homework question i juz needed ur help as to how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it for you, here are a few links that will help you figure this out for yourself:

1. [Fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html) lets you iterate through the members of your `NSArray`
2. If you get back an `NSRange` value from running [`-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfCharacterFromSet:) on each string, then the string contains the character you're looking for. If you get an `NSRange` value representing `{NSNotFound, 0}` then your string does not contain the character(s)
3. You can use [`-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:) to split each element of the array by your character
4. You can then use fast enumeration to iterate through each of these split components, using [`-stringByAppendingString`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString:) to glue them together

All those links will take you to Apple's documentation that explains each of the concepts and methods.

**EDIT** - Added Sbrocket's clarification.

Comment: Just a note: -rangeOfCharacterFromSet: doesn't return NULL if there is no match, it returns a NSRange value representing {NSNotFound, 0}. Check the documentation page you linked.

Comment: NSString *stringWithout = [myString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"4" withString:@""];

i am using this to separate 4 from my string but cannot find why it s not working

Comment: NSLog(@"original string: %@", myString);
stringWithout = [myString...];
NSLog(@"new string: %@", stringWithout);